# staticmethod and __init__ in OOP

Tags: python, oop

Good Morning,
I'm going through the book Dusty Phillips - Python 3 Object Oriented Programming.
There is an example of the class

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, square_feet='', beds='', baths='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_beds = beds
        self.num_baths = baths

    def display(self):
        print("PROPERTY DETAILS")
        print(f'square footage: {self.square_feet}')
        print(f'bedrooms: {self.num_beds}')
        print(f'baths: {self.num_baths}')
        print()
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(square_feet=input("Enter the square feet: "),beds=input("Enter number of bedrooms: "),baths=input("Enter number of baths: "))
```

and information that prompt_init - "This method uses the Python dict constructor to create a dictionary of values that can be passed into **init**. The value for each key is prompted with a call to input."
Question is, how method prompt_init as staticmethod could pass variables to **init**?
I completely don't understand what exactly is happening and how it might work like that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The author says that the dict _can_ be passed to `__init__` - but it is not in the code you have posted.

Comment: You'd probably have to pass the returned dictionary to the init method yourself, e.g. `p = Property(**Property.prompt_init())`.

Comment: It says 'it can be passed' so output of `prompt_init` is a dict and you can use it to init an instance of `Property` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, it's your responsibility to then pass the resulting `dict` to `__init__`:

```
 args = Property.prompt_init()
 p = Property(**args)
```

A class method that can do this for your would be more appropriate:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(...):
        ...  # As before

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls):
        square_feet = input("Enter the square feet: ")
        beds = input("Enter number of bedrooms: ")
        baths = input("Enter number of baths: ")
        return cls(square_feet, beds, baths)

p = Property.from_user_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt_init()` static method doesn't instantiate any property instance, just prompts the user for inputs and returns a dictionary of attributes that can be used for instantiating new instances.

As an example:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, square_feet='', beds='', baths='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_beds = beds
        self.num_baths = baths

    def display(self):
        print("PROPERTY DETAILS")
        print(f'square footage: {self.square_feet}')
        print(f'bedrooms: {self.num_beds}')
        print(f'baths: {self.num_baths}')
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(square_feet=input("Enter the square feet: "),beds=input("Enter number of bedrooms: "),baths=input("Enter number of baths: "))

inputs = Property.prompt_init()
new_property = Property(**inputs)
```

You can also define a factory static method to simplify this:

```
class Property:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def create_property():
        return Property(**Property.prompt_init())

new_property = Property.create_property()
```

or better yet, as a class method:

```
class Property:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def create_property(cls):
        return cls(**cls.prompt_init())

new_property = Property.create_property()
```

In either case, you still have to call the class constructor to create an instance, as `prompt_init()` doesn't do that.

Comment: @ImustAdmit if the question helped answer your question, you can mark your question as resolved . For more information, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers